# Linux bash script at times exits from a while true loop

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I have this simple script that keeps a log of the Bitcoin exchange rate. I found out that every few days the script would stop. To keep it going, I added a call to the script itself right after the infinite loop, but I would like to know why it exits. Thanks for any hint.

```
#!/bin/bash

# logfile
logfile=/var/log/bitcoin_log
# frequency of updates, in minutes
sleepmins=1
# url of the bitcoin exchange rates
url=https://blockchain.info/it/ticker
# timeout
timeout=120
# number of bitcoins
balance=1

let sleepsecs=$sleepmins*60

#infinite loop
while true
do
    eur=`curl -m $timeout -s $url | grep EUR |  awk '{print $11}'`
    eur=${eur::-1}
    eurwall=`echo $eur*$balance | bc`

    echo `date --rfc-3339=seconds`' '$eur' '$eurwall >> $logfile
    sleep $sleepsecs
done

# if the script breaks out of the infinite loop, write to the log and restart it
echo `date --rfc-3339=seconds`' '$0' pid '$$': exited the infinite loop' >> \
    $logfile

./btcwallet &
```

Comment: Bunch of bugs here that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch. Beyond that -- this is the wrong way to get a service to automatically restart on failure; it won't recover from any signal or other condition that kills the entire shell rather than only terminating the loop. Use the process supervision mechanism your operating system ships with -- on MacOS that's launchd, on current Fedora it's systemd, on many Debian and Ubuntu systems it's upstart, etc.

Comment: On which point: have you verified that your code to "fix" the problem really does so -- that "exited the infinite loop" is actually logged, etc?

Comment: I would also make sure you examine the stdout and stderr of the process.  Make sure you log those to a file as well.  I'm guessing curl is probably getting some sort of error

Comment: @Gary, sure, but curl getting an error won't actually exit the loop. Not unless the interpreter is started as `bash -e yourprog` or such. And even then it wouldn't exit unless `awk` had a nonzero exit status, unless `pipefail` were set.

Comment: BTW, if you're going to use `awk`, why do you need `grep` or `bc` at all? `awk` can do both filtering *and* math built-in.

Comment: ...now, if we were running on a memory-constrained system, and the `curl` pipeline emitted more content than we could store in a shell variable -- **that** could definitely kill the script. But it wouldn't just exit the loop, it'd actually *kill the script*, and the restart mechanism would fail too. (See again, re: "use a real process supervision system").

Comment: As it is, though, this question doesn't actually have enough to be answerable.